# How to use AND in workbench REST explorer

Tags: rest-api, workbench

Say I have a query that looks like

`/services/data/vXX.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+From+Account+WHERE+ShippingCity='San+Francisco'`

how would I add a condition like `zip=XXXXX`to this query? I tried using & but it didn't appear to filter anything out.

Comment: try to use                                                                             /services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+From+Account+WHERE+ShippingCity='San+Francisco'+AND+ShippingState='San' @Jezza

Comment: That executes just fine, but the actual query I'm running is /services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+From+opportunity+WHERE+Completed_Deal_Docs__c=NULL+AND+StageName!=Contract which is giving a malformed query error. Maybe its the !=, I'm not sure how to do NOT either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+From+opportunity+WHERE+Completed_Deal_‌​Docs__c=NULL+AND+StageName!='Contract'
```

You need quotes around the value being compared against field `stageName`

In general, best practice is to test the query in Developer Console and then paste into the REST Explorer